# java class "a" run method when class "a" created

Tags: java, class, object

how to run "print()" method when class a created as object? I want to run "print()" method right after the line "a obj = new a();"

I mean, just call the class, not the method. That it will operate immediately after the calling

```
class a {

    public static void print() {
        System.out.println("Hey!");
    }
    

}


public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        a obj = new a(); // I want to run print() method right after it

    }
}
```

Comment: call from constructor?

Comment: Without calling*, i'll edit it right now

Comment: What do you mean "without calling"? You do realize that this sounds like you are asking how you can get your program to do something without telling it to do something. This makes little sense. It would be very weird if software would call methods without the developers calling said methods in the source code.

Comment: Without any additional frameworks you can't run code automatically right after a constructor has been executed. Why don't you want to do the call in the constructor?

Comment: Because I want to execute the method before it will be possible to access variables that will be in class "a"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess if this is some sort of weird java puzzler (why the heck wouldn't you just put `print()` in the constructor?), you can put it in an initializer:

```
class a {
    { print(); }
    public static void print() {
        System.out.println("Hey!");
    }
}
```

will get the job done. But this is a very silly idea - at the class file level it's all the same thing, whether you do this or put the `print()` statement in a constructor. We're just nitpicking on language features at this point.

Perhaps take a step back. You had some unknown problem. You thought: I know! I'll just somehow make construction of objects of this class cause the print method to run, but without putting a call to print in the constructor! Oh, but, how do I do that - better ask SO.

That was the wrong thought. So state the unknown problem instead of a question about a bad 'solution'.

NB: You can also make static initializers, e.g:

```
class a {
    static { print(); }
    public static void print() {
        System.out.println("Hey!");
    }
}
```

And now print() will in fact run before that constructor. It'll also run only once, ever, that's the point of static initializers: They run the moment you so much as look funny at that `a` class (do anything with it at all), and after they've run they are never run again.

Your question is quite unclear, so I'm just taking wild stabs here.

Comment: Wow, that was deep! I'm sorry you feel that way. Anyway, you helped me, thanks. And I must learn to run a method before accessing variables, because I want to learn how the user will commit to make a "password" and then have access to the code